# To kow if an element in JS is disabled in CGI

Tags: javascript, cgi

How can I get to know in CGI script if an element in the Javascript is disabled.

I have disabled dropdown values whose values doesn't get passed on Submit. I can make these values equal to 1 if I could know if they are disable.

I have already tried enabling the elements on submission and disabling again, it works but I do not want to use this method as it doesn't give a good view to use.

Further, editing my question, is there a way I can have a variable common(global/sahred) between JS and CGI?

Comment: You can't - they run in different places. Please expand on what you want to do, I'm sure somebody will be able to come up with an idea.

Comment: why dont you ask CGI why he did it :-) have fun

Comment: Can you not base your logic on what "IS" submitted rather than what is not submitted? Considering it is your form and logic, you'll know what to look for on submission, and therefor know whats missing.

Comment: @betard Can youn please tell me how can I get to know what is submitted and what is not?                                        If i could know that this element is not submitted, That would work too for me.

Comment: I simply meant that your CGI can be written to look for everything, and if its null/"" then it wasn't sent.  I don't know pearl, but something along the lines of (pseudo-code) if (firstName == null) { submitted = false } else {submitted = true } - So because you created the forms and know all the available data you can possibly expect, you can then by process of elimination determine what was sent and what wasn't.  and in turn assign whatever values you want in either case.

Answer (score 0):

You can not 'share' a variable between JS and CGI because they are two different environments. JS runs on the client, CGI on the server.

In order to pass information of any sort, including the enabled/disabled status of an element you could use JavaScript to add a `<input type="hidden">` to the form so that the CGI script knows to output a disabled element next time it generates the form.

Rereading your question, it sounds like you are trying to get the value of a drop down which is not passed since the element is disabled?  In that case you can use the same technique, read the value of the drop down with JavaScript and put that value in another hidden form element.

Comment: So, if I use a hidden variable in HTML, modify it in JS(to tell if drop down was disabled), then can I use it in CGI?

Comment: It is not a variable, it is a form element just like the other `input` tags and your CGI script should be able to read it just like other form elements.  The only difference between a `<input type="hidden">` and a normal `<input>` is that the browser does not display it to the user.  It should be noted that hidden form elements although not usually seen by users, can be altered on the client side so never trust anything in them, sanitize it like any user submitted data.  Never store things like prices in it or suddenly you'll start selling things much cheaper than you expected.

Comment: I understand your idea but it is not working.May be I am doing a mistake somewhere. Here is html code: <input id="sDisabled" type="hidden" value="<!--#echo var="sDisabled"-->" />    . In JS: document.getElementById('sDisabledLO').value = "True"; gets set properly.  But in CGI I use: SSPEC_RESOURCE_ROOTVAR("sDisabledLO", sDisabledLO, PTR16, "%s") and to test teh variable:  if(!strncmp(sDisabledLO, "True", 4))      But the value in CGI doesn't get set.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand completely your question, but I think I can help you. Do you know JQuery? With JQuery you could add a function to an event, let's say onChange, and then send a value with Ajax if the value was changed or if the value was disabled. I could help you if you know JQuery, I could also put some code if you dont and try to explain. But first, is this what you want to achieve:

See if an element was disabled(or set to null or 0), send it to CGI script, and then return a message or change something within the page?